# NextJS and Cloudinary Problems

Tags: next.js, next.js13, cloudinary, nextjs-image

I have this problem in my console:

**results { error: { message: 'unknown api_key' } }**

It happens because I'm trying to get images from my Cloudinary account, I've verified my cloud name, api key, api secret.

The problem happens in this part of my code:

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const results = await     fetch(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/resources/image`, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY + ':' + process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET).toString('base64')}`
        }
    }).then(r => r.json());

    console.log('results', results);
    return {
        props: {

        }
    }
}
```

This is my .env.local

```
CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME="mycloudinary"
CLOUDINARY_API_KEY="mykey"
CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET="mysecret"
```

If someone could help me please!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a typo here. You're using NEXT_CLOUDINARY_API_KEY instead of
CLOUDINARY_API_KEY, which is the variable name specified in your .env.local file.

Replace NEXT_CLOUDINARY_API_KEY with CLOUDINARY_API_KEY.

```
Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY + ':' + process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET).toString('base64')}`
```

Comment: I have replaced but the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resolve it by removing the quotes from around the values in your `.env` file.

In addition, worth logging the value of all ENV variables in your function to ensure they do *actually* have a value set that you expect and is accessible.